# How to create an on-screen keyboard which will show which keys are being typed currently?

Tags: javascript, typing

I've got an online typing program and I want to create an on-screen keyboard for them, rather like how they do it in typing programs, such as Keyblaze Typing Tutor. So is there a way to create a JavaScript program which will display the keys (the presentation aesthetics don't matter) which are currently being typed by the user?

Comment: I've been looking online for things like jQuery on Screen Keyboard and similar plugins, but they only allow you to enter text into a textbox, they don't show anything when text is typed using the actual keyboard on your computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try extending this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AHPaY/6/)

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $("#input").keydown(function (event) {
      $("#" + String.fromCharCode(event.which)).addClass("trigger");
  }).keyup(function (event) {
      $("#" + String.fromCharCode(event.which)).removeClass("trigger");
  });
});​
```

You can create a keyboard using pure HTML and CSS. See this [beautiful example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/NED76/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 2):

You can find nice jQuery on Screen Keyboard Plugin on this [site](http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/). Read the documentation too.

[image]

It looks like this...